# React Native - How to Resize a View and Re-Render the page at runtime

Tags: react-native, rendering

I am developing an Audip Player app that has multiple views. Like this

```
<View style={{flex: 0.04}}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.pageTitle}</Text>
</View>
<View style={{flex: 0.90}}>
    <FlatList
    .....List of clickable Audios to sent to player.....
    />
</View>
<View style={{flex: this.state.playerSize}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.audioplayerbutton} onPress={() => this.resizeAudioPlayer()}>
        <Text style={styles.accentTextSmall}>ReSize</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>    
</View>
```

The bottom view has a button. I want the user to click on this to expand the size of the last View. Clicking again should bring it back to normal size. onPress has the followsing function attached to it.

```
resizeAudioPlayer () {

    this.state.playerSize =  (this.state.playerSize == 0.06) ? 1.5 : 0.06;
}
```

this.state.playerSize has the default value of 0.06 defined in the constructor.

The resizePlayer does get called successfully. However the View doesn't refresh and resize automatically. If I go to another page and come back I do see the resized views, but not while remaining on the same page. Any idea how to achieve this objective of resizing the bottom View? (others will shrink proportionately of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setState` to update the state otherwise you won't trigger a rerender. Just change the `resizeAudioPlayer` implementation to use this function.

```
resizeAudioPlayer() {
  this.setState({
    playerSize: (this.state.playerSize === 0.06) ? 1.5 : 0.06,
  });
}
```

**Update** - In case you want to set the state to a value that depends on the previous state (like in this scenario), it's a good idea to use an updater function.

```
resizeAudioPlayer() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    playerSize: (prevState.playerSize === 0.06) ? 1.5 : 0.06,
  }));
}
```